# gnuplot cannot connect to display

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnuplot

When I try to run gnuplot I get the following error.

```
sean@DESKTOP-EGDC4UU:/mnt/c/Users/Seang/Desktop/Microgen_CFD/OpenFOAM/SST$ gnuplot

        G N U P L O T
        Version 5.0 patchlevel 3    last modified 2016-02-21

        Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2016
        Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

        gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
        faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
        immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type set to 'qt'
gnuplot> plot x,sin(x)
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to existing gnuplot_qt. Starting a new one.
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

Warning: slow font initialization
gnuplot>
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Are you connecting to the machine remotely?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), running inside Windows 10

Comment: That's not quite what I was asking - are you by chance using Windows Subsystem for Linux (as suggested by the `/mnt/c/Users/` path)? if so, is there actually an X-server running?

Comment: Yes I'm using the subsystem. I'm sorry I'm new to linux, what do you mean by X-server?

Comment: I follow you now, so should I download Xming X Server for Windows to allow for graphical windows?

Comment: Please see [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on WSL as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-wsl-as-of-2018)