# How to perform process handling routines on a Ubuntu machine on a Windows system

Tags: windows, windows-10, process, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On my Windows 10 machine, I've installed a Ubuntu system (as a Trusted Microsoft Store app). When I open that window and type `help`, these are the first lines I see:

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

The results of `uname -a` are the following:

```
Linux DOMINIQUEDS 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

In that Ubuntu window, I have lots of interesting Linux/UNIX features, like `find`, `grep`, ..., but now I would like to do some process handling (`ps -ef`, `kill -9`), and this seems not to work:

When opening Windows task manager, I see ±100 processes running.

When I run `ps -ef`, (even after having opened the Ubuntu window as administrator), I only see three processes:

```
DominiqueDS@DOMINIQUEDS:~$ ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 17:14 ?        00:00:00 /init
Dominiq+     2     1  0 17:14 tty1     00:00:00 -bash
Dominiq+    18     2  0 17:19 tty1     00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Does anybody know how I can make `ps -ef` and `kill -9` work in this Ubuntu window on my Windows-10 machine?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't.
WSL Bash in Windows 10 runs in a kind of sandbox, and has no access to windows processes.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs):

> The proc filesystem provides a method of communication between kernel
>   space and user space. For example, the GNU version of the process
>   reporting utility `ps` uses the proc file system to obtain its data,
>   without using any specialized system calls.

The `ps` command allows you to control the Linux Kernel. On Windows 10 WSL (version 1) there is no Linux Kernel for the `ps` command to control. There is only a Windows 10 kernel.

Things may change in future WSL versions but for the time being you can enjoy learning about all the GNU utilities like `grep`, `sed` and even GUI apps if you install Ubuntu Desktop:

- [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018)