# Ubuntu app on WSL doesn't recognise Windows symlinks

Tags: symbolic-link, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019873/how-to-perform-process-handling-routines-on-a-ubuntu-machine-on-a-windows-system), I already asked a first question on the Ubuntu app on a Windows machine, this was about a Ubuntu app I installed on my computer at work.

Now I've tried to do the same with WSL on my computer at home, but it seems not to work.

First some general information:

First line of `help` result:

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

`uname -a` result:

```
Linux DESKTOP-D0GIHSU 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft #864-Microsoft Thu Nov 07 15:22:00 PST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've again used Windows `mklink C C:\` command for creating a Windows symlink in the root directory of my Ubuntu app, but this time it seems not to work:

Windows `dir` command result excerpt:

```
19/12/2019  14:35    <SYMLINKD>     C [C:\]
```

(I followed the link and while doing a `dir`, the results of `dir C:\` are shown, so it works)

Ubuntu app `ls -ltra | grep C` result:

```
ls: cannot access 'C': Input/output error
d?????????  ? ?    ?         ?            ? C
```

Anybody has an idea what's going wrong?
Thanks in advance