# Can I remotely access Ubuntu App on Windows 10 with support for a Desktop Environment?

Tags: networking, virtualization, windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access

Windows 10 now supports Linux apps such as Ubuntu, but there is no desktop environment. I'm wondering if there is a way to to support remote access to the Ubuntu app from the Windows 10 host PC or a different Windows 10 PC with support for a desktop environment by installing some packages into the Ubuntu app such as rdp or tightvncserver.

One problem I've run into is the Ubuntu app seems to share the Windows 10 host IP address.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. What do you mean by remote access to the "Ubuntu app"? Do you mean Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)? Since WSL does not support any GUI yet the only way youcan do it may be remote access to the terminal, by `ssh`. Is this something you want?

Comment: @user68186 I'm not sure if this is valid, but I was trying to get around the fact that WSL does not support a GUI by running the GUI via remote access. I'm interested in a desktop environment versus just remote terminal access via SSH, but I'm wondering if SSH will even work since the IP address seems to be shared and I don't know how to specifically address the Ubuntu app versus the Windows 10 host.

Comment: @user68186 I tried installing TightVNC Server in the Ubuntu app and TightVNC Viewer on Windows, but the connection is refused. I'm not sure I have TightVNC Server configured properly in the Ubuntu app, but I suspect the Windows 10 host is refusing the connection versus the Ubuntu app since the two share the same IP address.

Comment: I don't think it what you want will work. See [How to run GUI apps on WSL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-wsl-as-of-2018)