# WSL Ubuntu 18.04 XRDP problem

Tags: networking, windows, login, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xrdp

When I connect to ubuntu using RDP it show's me this message:

[image: Message]

I have a Kali Linux WSL installed too and it works fine but I have this problem with Ubuntu. Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on WSL as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-wsl-as-of-2018)

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved itself, I don't know what I did but I think that is execute the Appdiagnostic10 because I had to execute it and then I could login in the server.