# Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL): what can't I do with the Ubuntu application for Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

As most of you know, in the Microsoft Store, there are [three versions of Ubuntu](https://www.howtogeek.com/fyi/there-are-now-three-versions-of-ubuntu-in-the-microsoft-store-heres-why/). This means that on Windows I can emulate Ubuntu and have the Ubuntu command line directly on Windows.

The question is very easy: what can’t I do from the Ubuntu command line emulated in Windows that I can do on a proper Linux-based Ubuntu? Is it useful to download this Ubuntu application, install it, and work just with it instead of the real OS? Is it possible to install all the development libraries? Can I write (or not) device drivers? In other words: what are the limits?

What features of Ubuntu Linux-based are missing from Ubuntu-on-Windows?

New answers are welcome: I know that every software is always changing by improving characteristics and features!

Comment: If you've booted into Windows, perhaps for gaming, it's nice to have Ubuntu 16.04 installed there when you are on micro-breaks, reading Ubuntu Q&A's here and want to quickly check some commands out without rebooting. If you want the limitations of Ubuntu on Windows your best bet is to go to Microsoft's website and read all the new feature requests or bugs users have posted: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq

Comment: WSL is still [quite a lot slower](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=wsl-february-2018&num=2) in terms of I/O (disk operations), even compared to Linux virtual machines running on Windows. Though, this seems to be an area worked on by Microsoft.

Comment: @jpaugh, exactly, thanks! I have also just updated the question again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When this question was first written, neither WSL2 nor WSLg had been released, so the answer today is certainly different than it was a few years ago.  Some of that info has been updated in answers here, but I feel there's a lot missing in other answers here around actual "limitations".

I'm a fairly big WSL fan, but I'll be the first to acknowledge that there are quite a few limitations when it comes to WSL.  Fortunately, most of these have workarounds, but they do catch most new users off guard.

To start with, let me just lay out some "differences" between Ubuntu on WSL and a traditional Ubuntu installation on a VM or physical machine.  I'll reference some of these in the "limitations" section below:

1. WSL1 runs as a "syscall translation layer" that attempts to translate Linux kernel API's into those of the Windows kernel.
2. Ubuntu running in WSL2 acts more like a container.  It is running under a real Linux kernel in a managed virtual machine (that you can't access).  Ubuntu is running inside a namespace in that VM.  It is not, itself, directly running in a VM.
3. WSL has its own init system.  Its main job (other than some "normal" Linux init tasks) is to set up the interoperability between Linux and Windows.  For instance, it:

   - makes the Windows network available to Ubuntu
   - adds the Windows path to the environment
   - mounts Windows drives into Ubuntu
4. That init runs as PID 1 inside the Ubuntu WSL instance/namespace/container, unless you enable Systemd support, in which case Systemd becomes PID 1.
5. Starting WSL is not like booting a virtual or physical machine.  Many of the tasks that Ubuntu would normally (typically through Systemd) do during boot are either not needed for WSL or are actually harmful to its normal operation.
6. There is no concept of a "login" when starting WSL.  WSL detects the default user and automatically starts the shell defined for that user in `/etc/passwd`.  No password is requested or needed.

###### Limitations of WSL

With that in mind, here are some limitations that I can think of:

- **init/Systemd:**

  Out of the box, WSL still does not have Systemd enabled, but it [is available](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986), and now works on both Windows 10 and Windows 11.  Many docs, blog posts, etc. that you come across for various tasks (e.g. installing Docker) will assume that Systemd is enabled, so you'll need to either make sure that it is or learn [how to adapt without it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986).

  There *were* quite a few other Systemd-related limitations in this section, but they have been removed based on recent WSL improvements.
- **Access to physical hardware:** On WSL, you will have limited access to hardware:

  - *Serial ports:* WSL1 has access to serial ports at some level, but only as far as the syscall implementations go.  That said, it's possible to run some software on WSL1 that utilizes the serial ports that is not possible on WSL2.
  - *Physical drives:*  Older versions of WSL lacked the ability to access physical drives, but recent WSL releases now do include the ability to mount physical drives, as long as they aren't in use by Windows.

  However, USB mass storage devices are not directly supported unless you use a special kernel.

  - *Graphics:* This used to be more of a limitation, but WSL 1.0.0 added support for GUI applications with WSLg (for both Windows 10 and 11).  This support is through Wayland/XWayland/Weston running with an RDP backend.  Of course, there still isn't any *direct* access from X to the physical hardware, so there are some things that don't work just like their "pure" Ubuntu equivalent.

  One of the most common is in running desktop environments.  You'll find several question and answers here on Ask Ubuntu around this topic.

  - *GPU:*  Under recent Windows 10 versions, *some* GPU Compute tasks are available using a passthrough library and the *Windows* GPU drivers.

    Under Windows 11, some additional GPU Compute tasks have been added.
  - *USB:* USB devices are not directly accessible.  However, under WSL2 (both in Windows 10 and 11), they can be shared from Windows [using USB/IP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb) and then attached in Ubuntu.

    Note, though, that the stock WSL2 kernel does not include most device drivers for USB devices.  For instance, even the basic media capture (i.e. camera) drivers are not included.  However, you can build your own kernel for WSL2 and include the necessary drivers.  However, note that currently, I (and others) have not succeeded in capturing video from a USB camera in WSL.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72255353/11810933) on Stack Overflow for the progress-to-date.
- **Ubuntu boot device:** The primary boot virtual disk/partition for Ubuntu in WSL must be formatted ext4.  Although the WSL2 kernel supports additional filesystems such as btrfs, they can only be used for secondary partitions.
- **Tasks that rely on authentication/login:** Due to (6) above, certain tasks that rely on authentication will behave differently on WSL.  For instance, normally you would edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` to raise the limits (e.g. number of open files, priority/nice, etc.) for a user.  However, this is a file that is handled by PAM (the "pluggable authentication module") during *user login*.  Without an authenticated login, this file is never processed.  See workaround in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1327539/1165986) if you come across this.
- **Networking:** While this might belong under the "hardware" section, it probably deserves its own callout here.  WSL2's network currently runs under a virtual switch inside Hyper-V, and that switch is NAT'd from the rest of the network.  This means that you cannot easily access network services in WSL2 from other devices (computers, phones, etc.) on the local network without additional effort.

  The easiest workaround is to use WSL1 for this when possible.  There are [multiple other workarounds](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403545/1165986) as well.
- **VPNs:** Likewise, when connecting to certain VPN's which disable local traffic, WSL2 will lose networking, since it is "local" (but not localhost) network traffic.
- **Pen-testing:**  Some penetration testing tasks simply won't work under with WSL1 (because of the limited syscall translations) nor WSL2 (because hardware is virtualized).  Two areas stand out here:

  - Direct access to the wifi interface is not available (only a virtual ethernet device), so WLAN password cracking techniques will not work.  As a workaround, it should be possible to install a secondary USB WiFi dongle, pass it through via USB/IP as discussed above, and use it inside WSL2.  Note that you will need to build your own kernel with the appropriate drivers for the network dongle.
  - Because WSL2 is on a separate layer 2 network than your Windows host (and the rest of your network), it won't be possible to do any layer 2 scanning.  The above USB/IP workaround should work for this as well.
- **Performance:** In general, performance under WSL2 is pretty good.  However, there are a few caveats:

  - *WSL1:* WSL1 has slightly reduced performance on its "pseudo-ext4/overlay" filesystem.  However, WSL2 achieves near-native performance on ext4 filesystems.
  - *WSL2:* WSL2 takes a *huge* performance hit when accessing files on Windows drives, especially multiple, small files.  Checking out the WSL2 kernel on an NTFS drive takes over 10 minutes (but ~30 seconds otherwise).  It is highly recommended that you keep project files on the ext4 filesystem or use WSL1 when accessing Windows drives.

  I keep a WSL1 instance around primarily for the purpose of working with Windows drives when needed.

I'm sure I'll remember some more (or perhaps someone will point them out in the comments), and I'll add them in if needed.

Again, with the workarounds mentioned, most of these are not serious blockers for most WSL users.  However, they are the source of many questions that I've answered across the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: +1, nothing more to say

Answer (score 21):

The Ubuntu that runs under Windows 10 Subsystem for Linux is not a full distro. In fact, it's not Linux at all -- it has no Linux kernel. So you can't test or try kernel extensions, including drivers, because *you're not running Linux*.

If you want to do stuff like that, either install Ubuntu in a VM -- Win10 includes Hyper-V, but personally, I prefer VirtualBox, which is free -- or dual-boot your machine with Ubuntu running on the bare metal. You will almost certainly find the latter faster than running Windows -- I do on all my machines. Partly this is because you need antivirus protection when running Windows, which saps performance, especially disk performance. And because you need it, Win10 includes built-in antivirus.

With Linux, you do not need any, so there is less performance impact.

Comment: Why do you think that you do not need antivirus on Linux?

Comment: It's the first time I've heard of this Ubuntu emulation app in Windows. Is this just like an alternative to enabling the now built-in (but disabled by default) bash shell in Windows 10 and something comparable to Cygwin but with an actual GUI? I'm wondering why anyone would use it.

Comment: @SeligkeitIstInGott It's not an emulator. It's a compatibility layer, just like for Wine on Linux.

Comment: @SeligkeitIstInGott the bash shell that is built-in is what they are talking about. I think Microsoft just marketed it as a bash shell because that is something people wanted, but really it's more sophisticated than just a bash shell.

Comment: @SeligkeitIstInGott It's the Ubuntu userland running on the Windows Subsystem for Linux compatibility layer. It's not an emulator, and there's no GUI. This might help: [How to Install and Use the Linux Bash Shell on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)

Comment: @CaptainMan said the magic words. What I needed to know is that the "bash shell" in Windows is the same as this "Ubuntu application". Didn't know the specifics of that "shell" before. Thanks.

Comment: @wjandrea It is indeed possible to get a GUI (sort of). I regularly start a WSL bash shell, where I start sshd, then use Putty to forward X11 stuff which is rendered by XMing.

Comment: "With Linux, you do not need any [antivirus], so there is less performance impact." -- Linux [is not immune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware) to viruses/malware/etc. Antivirus SW is useful in Linux both to protect yourself and to prevent bad stuff from spreading to other environments (e.g. Windows). I know it is not normally used, but that doesn't mean the threat doesn't exist.

Comment: I have issue with this. 1. Antivirus is not "required" to run windows. The windows operating system will run without an antivirus. It also comes with an antivirus, which leads to point 2: picking random software to point at as "slowing down the OS" seems arbitrary - what if I argued that ubuntu was slower because I needed a bunch of extra software to get apps working that only work in Windows? (like a VM so I could play AAA games?).  3. You have provided no evidence to support this claim.

Comment: Is there a technical term for this type of deception by Microsoft?

Comment: @Steve You don't even need SSH. Simply `export DISPLAY=:0` (or the appropriate display number depending on your X server).

Comment: @Hack-R There is no deception. They have been [quite clear](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/) from the beginning that this is not the actual Linux kernel. It started off as "running Linux tools, especially Bash" to "running Linux environments/distributions/applications". If any of that is deceptive, so is WINE.

Comment: @Bob Don't get me started on Wine! You think you have have 2 or 3 glasses without a headache, but nope. :) jk. OK, so of course they're transparent on a legal level. *But the serious part* of my jokey comment is that I have read in many industry and general news papers about the MS "infiltrate and destroy" strategy. This looks like part of it, like MS R. They come with a legal, intellectual, cultural trojan horse to make you think you're using the open source thing they hate but progressively capturing users in both technologically and, eventually, in the long game - in billing.

Comment: It's not as if they have not had subsystems before, remember the OS/2 Subsystem in NT3.51 ?  Just about any curses app will run, It's a death knell for Cygwin, but yes there are limitations. If you need to break past them then VirtualBox or similar. It's why they call it bash on Windows. It can halve your configuration items not to have to maintain separate bat/cmd/ps1 scripts for AWS, say.

Comment: Re the distinction between "service", "subsystem", "emulator" etc. There's a lot of disinformation being bandied around here.

NT has always included "personalities", from the first version, NT 3.1 in 1993.

NT came with 3: Win32, OS/2 & POSIX. The latter 2 only supported text-mode apps. The native NT API is never normally exposed: apps use a personality layer which translates it to something else. Win32 is just one of these.

The POSIX layer evolved into "Services for Unix", was replaced by Interix from Softway, & now has evolved into a Linux-binary-compatible version. It's nothing new.

Comment: @Zymus I stand by my assertion. It is *not safe* to run Windows without antivirus. Even for expert users who know not to run untrusted binaries, there are exploits involving compromised WMF, help files and more. This is not true of Linux, which is far less vulnerable. Yes there are Linux trojans & exploits, mainly for Internet servers, but it is at (conservatively) 2-3 orders of magnitude less risk. It is perfectly normal & safe to run Linux workstations with no antimalware. Windows is more vulnerable, by design. It's mainly due to marketing's insistence on ease of use, but it's true.

Comment: @LiamProven Linux is just as vulnerable as Windows, because there's only so much the OS can do to stop users from shooting themselves in the foot. You haven't answered my question of "Why do you think that you do not need antivirus on Linux?", and the response looks like something I'd see out of a Gentoo forum. Not to devolve the comment thread past it's usability anymore, but do you have verifiable evidence that Linux servers are at (conservatively) 2-3 orders of magnitude less risk?

Comment: It took me some time to write this up in reasonable detail. A response is here: https://liam-on-linux.livejournal.com/61110.html

I submit that it is a verifiable, objective fact that Windows is a more vulnerable OS family, due to the nature of both its design and its implementation.

Additionally, it is impossible to judge this matter in terms of statistical or evidential analysis without access to parallel universes in which Windows were _not_ a dominant OS and in which as a minority offering its vulnerability to attack was measurable compared to a dominant ecosystem of different OSes.

Answer (score 14):

*There are many useful pieces of information on each of the above answers. I am here summarizing the main concepts of each of them.*

**Update April 2020**: Pro and cons in using WSL are [here](https://itsfoss.com/windows-linux-kernel-wsl-2/) explained. There is clear why having a real Linux kernel is an advantage!! Additionally, [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) there is a guide to install WSL 2 onto your Windows 10. If you have installed the WSL 1 and you want to pass to WSL 2, [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel) you can find the instruction for doing it.

**Update August 2019**:
The new **WSL 2** was released (read [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-is-now-available-in-windows-insiders/) for more information). It seems that you can work with a real Linux kernel and with a Linux file system. Honestly, I haven't tried the new version so far (it is on my TODO list).

**Update May 2019**: as pointed out in one of the most recent answers, WSL is evolving by using the real Linux Kernel and giving many more options. I have been through [this document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/) and, if confirmed, it will be a big step forward. [Here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/05/ubuntu-support-windows-subsystem-linux-2) you can find a nice article about the topic "real Linux kernel on W10"

**Answer July 2018**
**Summarizing:**
"Ubuntu on windows is the complete Ubuntu userland on top of a Windows kernel in Linux-Compatibility mode", as point out in one of the comments.

*What I can't do:*

- Officially, no graphics interface supported so far. This means also that graphics applications cannot be executed. Additionally, the standard GUIs of the classic Ubuntu Linux-based are not supported for this reason of course.
- The kernel of Linux developed by Linus is NOT part of the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). This means that you cannot develop drivers and try it directly.
- Not every command line works.

*What I can do:*

- Use the command line and the basic Bash shell. It is possible to write and execute scripts.
- Develop applications (compile or cross-compile and execute them) but with no graphics so far.
- Use "apt-get" to install/remove new/old packets.

*Additional information:*

- other distributions are officially supported (like, for example, Debian and Kali)
- these applications are free, downloadable from the Windows Store and [here](https://www.linux.com/blog/learn/2018/2/how-get-started-using-wsl-windows-10) you can find the instruction to install and use it.
- [In this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-wsl-as-of-2018) of the blog, some suggestion on how to use a GUI for WSL (unofficial, third party)

Answer (score 7):

One of the things you cannot easily do under the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is run Linux GUI applications.

To do so you have to install an unsupported X11 server such as VcXsrv or Xming.

Enabling WSL is relatively trivial. It seems to be pretty good as a Linux command-line userland.

Comment: I wouldn't call `VcXsrv` unsupported. They've released about 10 updates since I've been using it (October 2017).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: I meant unsupported by Miscrosoft, in the sense in which they support WSL by implementing the kernel API, distributing the Ubuntu userland, providing tools to install/enable WSl and so on.

Answer (score 4):

From [How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/):

> [It] doesn’t yet support background server software, and it won’t officially work with graphical Linux desktop applications. Not every command-line application works, either, as the feature isn’t perfect.

Update from [allquixotic's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051525/windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-what-cant-i-do-with-the-ubuntu-application-f#comment1718082_1051594):

> As of Windows 10 v1803 background tasks *are* supported.

Comment: As of Windows 10 v1803 background tasks *are* supported.

Comment: It might be helpful to point out "background tasks" = `crontab` and other daemons. Here is a practical example of loading `crontab` when Windows boots up. Then using `rsync` every 2 days to backup Windows database: https://blog.snowme34.com/post/schedule-tasks-using-crontab-on-windows-10-with-wsl/index.html

Answer (score 4):

As of May 2019, [WSL 2 is under development](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/).

> **Dramatic file system performance increases**, and full system call
>   compatibility, meaning you can run more Linux apps in WSL 2 such as
>   Docker.
>
> ...
>
> WSL 2 uses an entirely new architecture that uses **a real Linux kernel**.
>
> ...
>
> Initial builds of WSL 2 will be available through the Windows insider program by the end of June 2019.

(emphasis mine)