# How to install git on Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051525/windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-what-cant-i-do-with-the-ubuntu-application-f), on Windows Subsystem for Linux I can do many many things using the command line. I am wondering if it is possible to install Git. I have tried using

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

but the result is:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package git
```

Some suggestions?

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update` yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might need to add the package first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: I didn't need to do step 1 to get get installed on WSL Ubuntu 18.04, but until I did, I could only get git 2.17 despite 2.27 being latest at time of this comment.  Thanks!

Comment: I had the exact same problem. I followed the steps at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324629/210901 `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get upgrade &&
sudo apt-get install git -y` in case it goes away.

Comment: This is helpful for WSL2 too. WSL2 comes with focal and git 2.25.1. While that version may be sufficient for some users, the others get use the git-core PPA to upgrade git to the latest version. For example, I needed the latest git-p4.py, which required a newer git.