# WSL in Windows 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: boot, gui, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just downloaded the Windows 10 Ubuntu app. when I click on the app, it brings up a command line interface (I think interface is what it is called) but I do not know how to bring up the Ubuntu GUI. Is there a manual to tell how to start the app and open Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018)

Answer (score 3):

Windows Subsystem for Linux is not designed to run a GUI. It's command line only, although [some very well behaved GUI apps can be run if an x.org server is installed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux#Limitations) within WSL.

If you need to run Ubuntu from within Windows, the appropriate method is virtualization. Windows can host virtualization if your PC is capable of it. As an example, here's the [system requirements for VirtualBox](https://geek-university.com/oracle-virtualbox/system-requirements/), a free virtualization app which supports Ubuntu as a guest and Windows as a host. (or vice versa).  Full Circle magazine [issue 153](http://dl.fullcirclemagazine.org/issue153_en.pdf) has a useful VirtualBox tutorial starting on page 23.

Other [virtualization hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtualization_software) will also accomplish this.

Comment: Think this link will answer some of your questions.  You have to remember you are running only a partial Ubuntu, not the full OS.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051525/windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-what-cant-i-do-with-the-ubuntu-application-f?rq=1