# Display Image, cannot reach X server

Tags: display, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am doing a project displaying some images with Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows.
However, after some trials, I get the following message "display-im6.q16: unable to open X server `' @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/432."

Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this ?
Thanks !

Comment: *"Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows"* meaning WSL - or something else?

Comment: Yes, I use WSL.

Comment: Please take a look at [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018)

Comment: Are you running WSL version 1 or Version 2? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177729/wsl-am-i-running-version-1-or-version-2

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051525/windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-what-cant-i-do-with-the-ubuntu-application-f?rq=1 may also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You just need an X server.  Get XMing from

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/
```

Install it, and run it before you launch any programs that require an X server.

Modify your .profile and add

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```