# ulimit -n command shows no change inspite of modifying the /etc/security/limits.conf file

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ulimit

While compiling [peridigm](https://github.com/peridigm/peridigm), I am facing the following error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/local/bin/trilinos-12.12.1/lib/libgaleri-xpetra.a: Too many open files
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/local/bin/trilinos-12.12.1/lib/libgaleri-epetra.a: Too many open files
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/local/bin/trilinos-12.12.1/lib/libaztecoo.a: Too many open files
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/local/bin/trilinos-12.12.1/lib/libisorropia.a: Too many open files
.
.
.
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o: Too many open files
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/io/mesh_input/quick_grid/unit_test/CMakeFiles/ut_QuickGrid_solidCylinder_np1.dir/build.make:1465: recipe for target 'src/io/mesh_input/quick_grid/unit_test/ut_QuickGrid_solidCylinder_np1' failed
make[2]: *** [src/io/mesh_input/quick_grid/unit_test/ut_QuickGrid_solidCylinder_np1] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1009: recipe for target 'src/io/mesh_input/quick_grid/unit_test/CMakeFiles/ut_QuickGrid_solidCylinder_np1.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/io/mesh_input/quick_grid/unit_test/CMakeFiles/ut_QuickGrid_solidCylinder_np1.dir/all] Error 2
.
.
[ 58%] Linking CXX static library libPeridigmLib.a
[ 58%] Built target PeridigmLib
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I used the instructions in [link](http://woshub.com/too-many-open-files-error-linux/) to increase the soft and hard limit of the processes by using the following:

```
#@student        -       maxlogins       4

* hard nofile 97816
* soft nofile 97816
session required pam_limits.so

# End of file
```

However, even after restarting the wsl terminal after updating the limit.conf file as instructed in the link, the `ulimit -n` still shows `1024` instead of the modified value. Why is it not changing? Any advice?

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What WSL build version do you have? it appears that support for `ulimit -n` was not implemented until [16257](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-16257)

Comment: @steeldriver My OS Version:  10.0.19042 N/A Build 19042

Comment: In that case I don't know - sorry

Answer (score 4):

`/etc/security/limits.conf` is a PAM construct.  Normally PAM would process this during your user login in a "normal" Linux, but ... you don't really "log in" in WSL, so [PAM doesn't get called](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1688#issuecomment-518802498).

The workaround, as described later that [same Github thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1688#issuecomment-532767317) is to run `sudo su $USER`, `sudo su - $USER`, or something along those lines (see the thread for other suggestions).  The resulting shell will have processed `limits.conf` through PAM, and you should be able to raise the limits there as expected (`ulimit -n 97816`, it sounds like from your question).  As long as peridigm's build stays in that subshell, you will hopefully be okay.

Clearly, this isn't ideal, but hopefully it gets you past this hurdle.

Comment: Can confirm that `sudo su $USER` worked with `WSL2` and `Ubuntu`. Was having this issue with `node js` with error `EMFILE: too many open files`

Answer (score 0):

Just use
`sudo su $USER --shell /bin/bash --command "ulimit -n"`

Comment: Some references needed for this.