# Running gnome-software on Windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnome-software

I have Ubuntu installed in Windows 10 (using WSL) and I have installed an X-server VcXsrv. I'm trying to run the Gnome software center.

I run `gnome-software` from the terminal.

The window appears but no graphics and an error message saying

> Unable to get list of updates: failed to get updates for refesh: Could not connect: No such file or directory

The errors in the terminal are:

```
$ gnome-software
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
20:58:54:0575 GLib-GObject invalid (NULL) pointer instance
20:58:54:0576 GLib-GObject g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
20:58:54:0576 GLib-GObject g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
20:58:54:0578 GLib-GObject invalid (NULL) pointer instance
20:58:54:0579 GLib-GObject g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
20:58:54:0581 GLib-GObject g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
20:58:54:0661 Gs  enabled plugins: desktop-categories, fwupd, os-release, packagekit-local, packagekit-offline, packagekit-proxy, packagekit-refine-repos, packagekit-refresh, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit-url-to-app, packagekit, systemd-updates, ubuntuone, appstream, desktop-menu-path, generic-updates, hardcoded-blacklist, hardcoded-featured, hardcoded-popular, modalias, packagekit-refine, rewrite-resource, steam, ubuntu-reviews, provenance, icons, provenance-license, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
20:58:54:0662 Gs  disabled plugins: dpkg, dummy, repos, shell-extensions, epiphany, odrs, packagekit-history, snap
20:58:54:0828 Gs  failed to connect to upower: Could not connect: No such file or directory
20:58:54:0828 Gs  not GsPlugin error from plugin fwupd g-io-error-quark:1: Failed to connect to system D-Bus: Could not connect: No such file or directory
20:58:54:0829 Gs  failed to call gs_plugin_refresh on fwupd: Failed to connect to system D-Bus: Could not connect: No such file or directory
20:58:54:0831 Gs  failed to call gs_plugin_refresh on packagekit-refresh: failed to get updates for refresh: Could not connect: No such file or directory
20:58:54:0901 Gs  failed to call gs_plugin_add_updates on fwupd: Failed to connect to system D-Bus: Could not connect: No such file or directory
20:58:54:0912 Gs  failed to call gs_plugin_refine on packagekit-refine: failed to search file /usr/share/metainfo/org.gnome.Software.Plugin.Epiphany.metainfo.xml: Could not connect: No such file or directory
20:58:54:0945 Gs  Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
20:58:54:0946 Gs  hiding category audio-video featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
20:58:54:0961 Gs  hiding category productivity featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
20:58:54:0966 Gs  failed to get featured apps: no apps to show
20:58:54:0972 Gs  Only 0 apps for popular list, hiding
20:58:55:0046 Gs  failed to call gs_plugin_add_updates_historical on fwupd: Failed to connect to system D-Bus: Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

Unfortunately I don't understand what this is telling me. Anyone know how to get it working?

Is running this on Windows for some reason a bad idea? Windows warns against using Windows tools to modify Linux files, so I thought I'd try the Linux tools.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting precisely the error you have quoted above.

I solved this problem by installing and configuring DBUS per the corresponding part of the long answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1005055/148933

Here's what it looks like in an XWindow running on VcXsrv.

[image]