# Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL): X error of failed request: BadWindow (invalid window parameter)

Tags: gui, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xserver

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), and I have just installed xcrysden on it with no apparent problem, however when I try to run it, I repeatedly get the Following error:

```
X Error of failed request: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request: 3
  ResourceID in failed request: 0xffffffff
  Serial number of failed request: 761
```

Now running graphical interfaces in WSL is a bit annoying. To do it, I use the [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) X server for Windows. I set the DISPLAY variable via `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`, and that does the trick for me. I can run for example gnuplot with no problem this way.

Why does xcrysden fail to launch in this situation?

Here is the full STDERR Stream that I get:

```
Running on platform : unix
Operating system : Linux Package ImageMagick's convert: /usr/bin/convert
Package ImageMagick's import: /usr/bin/import
Package Ppmtompeg: /usr/bin/ppmtompeg
Package Babel: /usr/bin/babel
Executing: /usr/lib/xcrysden/ftnunit
X Error of failed request: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
    Major opcode of failed request: 3
    ResourceID in failed request: 0xffffffff
    Serial number of failed request: 759
X Error of failed request: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
    Major opcode of failed request: 3
    ResourceID in failed request: 0xffffffff
    Serial number of failed request: 761
Error in startup script: Togl: couldn't get visual
    while executing
"togl .mesa -width 400 -height 400 -ident
.mesa -rgba true -redsize 1 -greensize 1 -blu..."
    (procedure "PlaceGlobWin" line 105)
    invoked from within
"PlaceGlobWin 0 [expr round(650 * $fac1)] [expr round(650 * $fac1)]"
    (procedure "ViewMol" line 25)
    invoked from within
"ViewMol ."
    invoked from within
"if [file exists $filedir] {
                # pop-up Viewer
                ViewMol .
                openExtStruct 3 crystal external  [list sh $system(TOPDIR)/scripts/pwi2xsf.sh]  pwi2xsf..."
    (procedure "parseComLinArg" line 89)
    invoked from within
"parseComLinArg [lrange $argv 2 end]"
invoked from within
"if { [llength $argv] > 2 } {
    parseComLinArg [lrange $argv 2 end]
} else {
    ViewMol .
}"
    (file "/usr/share/xcrysden/Tcl/xcInit.tcl" line 609)
X Error of failed request: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
    Major opcode of failed request: 12
    ResourceID in failed request: 0xffffffff
    Serial number of failed request: 764
```

Comment: Check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`  for error notices.

Comment: Well... I Don't have such a file in my /var/log folder

Comment: Don't think there is any guarantee that all X programs will work with WSL. I see several quirks with standard XFCE and Gnome programs, and crysden seems to use quite advanced graphics.

Comment: Try using **VcXsrv** instead of Xming: https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018/993331#993331