# Can't use gedit on Ubuntu App for Windows

Tags: gedit

My story is:

I download Ubuntu App for Windows to use the Fenics Library, as fenicsproject.org tells.
I installed Fenics Library.
Now i would to create a file to write my code, but when run:

`gedit test.py`

the answer is:

> Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
>   (gedit:16): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:04:53.373: cannot open display:

I already installed the `gedit` with command `sudo -apt gedit` ( or some like this, i don't remember ).

Thank to yall

Comment: Related: [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018)

Answer (score 1):

I faced this similar problem a while ago, this is what I did:
First install VcXsrv from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/
After installing, launch "Xlaunch" and complete the configuration.
When done, open the Ubuntu terminal and type the following:

```
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0
. ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
export DISPLAY=localhost0.0
.~/.bashrc
```

Now try any gedit...

```
gedit
```

BOOOM!DONE!

Comment: This worked for me with the exception it was `DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:1.0`. If anyone else encounters this problem of the port being incorrect, right-click `Show Log` from the tray. The correct `DISPLAY` address will be somewhere in there.