# Right Click to Paste in Windows

Tags: command-line, copy-and-paste

I am using Ubuntu in Windows. I only use it to paste API commands from Excel. Until today I copied in Excel and then right clicked in Ubuntu. Today nothing is happening when I right click and if I try Control Shift V I get ^v in the terminal. As all I do is open Ubuntu, paste in the command, and then close Ubuntu I can't have changed any settings.

I did notice that usually when I open Ubuntu I get a few lines of text appear (I think login type stuff) but today it is opening directly at the prompt.

How do I get the paste functionality back.

Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu WSL uses cmd as front end. So settings for CMD will be applied to Ubuntu as well. Does right click paste in CMD?. Check CMD settings. Moreover what you mean by "opening directly in prompt"? A screenshot can be helpful.

Comment: Use VcXsrv with clipboard enabled solves this I believe but cannot verify from my phone: https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018

Comment: I worked out the solution.  Somehow QuickEdit Mode became disabled.  I right clicked on the top bar, selected Properties and re-enabled it.  Works fine now.

Comment: @LondonTrader could you please post that as an answer and accept it? That way the question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out the solution. Somehow QuickEdit Mode became disabled. I right clicked on the top bar, selected Properties and re-enabled it. Works fine now.