# Editing .bashrc in WSL safely

Tags: bash, bashrc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How do I edit the `.bashrc` file in Windows Subsystem for Linux safely?

[This article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/) warns to never edit files stored in the WSL `AppData` folder using Windows tools.

But then how do you edit files like `.bashrc` in a safe manner?

Comment: Use the bash terminal to do edits via vim!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen you're advising a lifetime Windows user to use Vim? what kind of sadist are you? at least advise `nano`

Comment: @tatsu my appologies!

Answer (score 9):

Use the built-in `nano` editor as:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

The most important shortcuts for `nano` are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save the file and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close the editor.

A simple guide for using `nano` can be found in the [Gentoo Linux Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nano).

Answer (score 4):

I think [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) works fine. Just install the [Remote - WSL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) extension.

To use it just open cmd and type `bash`. In `bash` type `cd`, then use `code .bashrc`.

Voila! VS Code opens in WSL and you can edit the files you want.

Comment: Fyi. Complains, asking for WSL2

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to add yet another answer here, but the question itself (along with all the other answers here) needs **context** that is missing for anyone else coming along and trying to understand it.

The Microsoft warning that is linked in the original question refers to editing WSL1 files *through Windows* using Windows' `%AppData%` path.  In WSL version 1 (but not version 2), WSL stored the entire filesystem for the Linux instance in a Windows folder.  Those files, while visible to the user in Windows, should not be edited in Windows.  As the warning says, corruption of the WSL instance is likely if unheeded.

This is not a problem on WSL version 2. Since the filesystem is stored in a virtual disk, it's just not possible to edit the filesystem directly anyway.

On either version, however, it *is* safe to edit the files (including `~/.bashrc`) *inside* the WSL instance.  There, it's just a normal file in the WSL filesystem.  The two answers from 2019 ([BeastOfCaerbannog's](https://askubuntu.com/a/1148470/618353) and [WinEunuuchs2Unix's](https://askubuntu.com/a/1148506/618353)) utilize this approach.  Nothing wrong with that - they are both correct answers.  Although I'd say that installing a Windows X Server and `gedit` just to edit a WSL file is probably overkill.  Just about any other editor could have been cited as well (does someone want to throw in an Emacs answer for completeness? ;-)).

The [2020 answer from Brixton Mavu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1280588/618353), which mentions using VSCode, is also a spin on the same idea.  Even though it uses a Windows tool, VSCode launches a server inside the WSL instance with which it communicates to allow editing, browsing, and even debugging of the WSL instance.

Then there's [@Jon's recent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1339120/618353) (which bumped this question, and is why I saw it).  This is (mostly) the correct answer for how to safely edit WSL files from inside Windows, rather than from inside the WSL instance.  It's actually already mentioned, though, in the Microsoft blog entry that was linked in the original question.

I say "mostly", because you should, in general, avoid using Windows tools to edit Linux files, since many Windows editors default to using DOS/Windows line-endings, which will cause `~/.bashrc` to fail as well.  Some tools are smart enough to recognize that the existing file is a Linux file, some tools aren't, but most tools will default to CRLF (DOS/Windows) in absence of any other format.

If the WSL instance won't start due to an error in the `~/.bashrc`, then you *could* use @Jon's suggestion of `\\wsl$\` to edit it, but there are also (IMHO) other, safer alternatives.

To edit the `~/.bashrc` when that file is preventing you from launching, run:

```
wsl -e bash --norc -c "vi ~/.bashrc"
```

or

```
wsl ~ -e bash --norc
vi .bashrc
```

This will launch `bash` without sourcing the existing `~/.bashrc`.

Other alternatives include launching the session as root:

```
wsl -u root
```

And then make any needed edits.

WSL, in general, has some amazing recovery mechanisms through the use of the `wsl` command's arguments to starting the instance.

Answer (score 3):

Open Windows File Explorer and type `\\WSL$` in the address bar.  This will open a pseudo-share that WSL provides for each *running* WSL instance where it is safe to edit the files.

Note that the instance does need to be started and running for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a GUI editor then install `VcXsrv` as detailed here:

- [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018/993331#993331)

Then use `gedit ~/.bashrc`