# Run ubuntu-desktop on WSL (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: desktop-environments, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running 18.04 LTS on Windows subsystem for Linux (WSL). I have installed the Ubuntu Desktop by running

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

However, when I start Linux only the terminal starts.
How do I get the Desktop to start?

Comment: When it comes to WSL and Ubuntu, I gave it a go and found it frustratingly hard to get the Unity desktop experience to work. There are guides out there, but, what I ended up doing is running Ubuntu in Hyper-V instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018)

Comment: @StephenQuan You should consider posting an answer on that here or on the duplicate link.

Comment: As of today, GUI apps are natively supported by wsl2 on Windows 10 build 21364+. Detailed blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/the-initial-preview-of-gui-app-support-is-now-available-for-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2/

Comment: @MatějŠtágl You can post this as an answer.  Hopefully, eventually it will get updated to be the accepted answer.  I'm sure there are a number of these types of questions across the Stack Exchange network that will need to be updated.

Comment: moderator @Thomas Ward deleted my answer yesterday and converted it to a comment without explaining anything. Just a big lol. Apparently trash mods are not exclusive to SO.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-ward Thomas feel free to elaborate on what's wrong with my answer

Comment: Honestly, I came back here to comment again, thinking maybe I was jumping the gun on recommending this as an "answer".  Since this is still in Insider/Preview, it's probably premature for it to be an answer.  This is similar to the current "Hot Meta Post" you'll find on the right which talks about "future release features" being off-topic.

Answer (score 14):

Windows 10 itself does not support GUI. In order to run GUI in wsl you need to install a X server and get it to configure correctly.

I would suggest you to install **VcXsrv** to display GUI.

I am not able to run GUI successfully by `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. However, I successfully installed mate-desktop GUI in **Debian** and **ubuntu**.

Here are the steps for me to display GUI by wsl. You can check my videos on detailed steps [Install GUI (mate desktop) to Microsoft Windows Subsystem Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjogEWudpaM)

**step 1:** 
  install Debian or Ubuntu Linux subsystem:
    - PowerShell as administrator: `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` 
    - Microsoft Store: install "Debian" or "ubuntu"

**step 2:** 
  install mate tesktop for **Debian**:
    - open Debian in windows 10. Type the following commend
    - `sudo apt-get update`
    - `sudo apt install task-mate-desktop`

**OR** install mate-desktop for **Ubuntu**
- open Ubuntu console in windows 10
- `sudo apt install tasksel`
- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo tasksel install ubuntu-mate-desktop`

**step 3:** 
  install **VcXsrv** in windows 10:
    - download from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/
    - open XLauch, and use the following options for setup
      `- select: "One large window"
      - Display number: 0
      - next
      - Start no client
      - next 
      - finish`

**step 4:** 
  setup display in linux console: 
    - `export DISPLAY=:0`
    - `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1`

**step 5:** 
  start Mate-desktop environment: 
    - run `mate-session`

Step 3 and step 4 are extremely important to display GUI in windows 10 wsl.

Comment: If you repost your answer on the duplicate candidate above your answer will help a larger audience.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks. I will paste my solution to the duplicate candidate

Comment: I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why this wasn't working. It turns out that these are instructions for WSL version 1. If you are running WSL 2, you need to set `export DISPLAY=$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2>/dev/null):0`

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL#Running_Graphical_Applications

Answer (score 3):

As great as WSL is, it's really not designed for that sort of thing.

If your goal is to get the full Ubuntu Desktop, it makes a lot more sense to just install a full Ubuntu Virtual Machine, using something like Virtualbox, Hyper-V, etc. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, I solved my problem by partitioning my disk and installing a full Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: That is a __`Dual-boot`__, which means you never solved the problem posed by your question, which is asking in reference to the tag-name `Windows-Subsyem-for-Linux`.

Answer (score 3):

@gus33000 posted a working solution on Twitter:

https://twitter.com/gus33000/status/1188517307867381761

> quick rundown for people wanting to recreate this:
>
> Install VcXsrv
>
> Install WSL
>
> Install Ubuntu from the store
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade
>
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
>
> sudo service dbus start
>
> sudo service x11-common start
>
> gnome-shell --x11 -r

Answer (score 3):

### [image]
The following instructions were copied and pasted from an article I wrote but it lost the original formatting, links, and screenshots:

**Source:** [How to Install Ubuntu Desktop with a Graphical User Interface in WSL2](https://thealtruist.medium.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-with-a-graphical-user-interface-gui-in-wsl2-5c188c0a261a)

---

Download VcXsrv:
Visit the official website
Click "Download"

---

Install VcXsrv:
Open "vcxsrv-64.1.20.8.1.installer.exe"
Click "Next"
Click "Install"
Click "Close"

---

Allow Access to VcXsrv:
Check "Private Networks"
Click "Allow Access"

---

Open PowerShell:
Press "⊞ Windows"
Enter "PowerShell" into the search bar
Right-click "Windows PowerShell"
Click "Run as Administrator"

---

Open WSL2:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`wsl`

---

Install Ubuntu Desktop:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo apt --yes install ubuntu-desktop`

---

Set the Username Variable:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`username=$(wslvar USERNAME)`

---

Create the Ubuntu Directory:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`mkdir --parents /mnt/c/users/$username/.ubuntu/`

---

Open the Ubuntu Directory:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`cd /mnt/c/users/$username/.ubuntu`

---

Download Linux Software Repository for Microsoft Products:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

**Ubuntu 20.04:**
`wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb --output-document packages-microsoft-prod.deb`
**Ubuntu 18.04:**
`wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb --output-document packages-microsoft-prod.deb`

---

Install Linux Software Repository for Microsoft Products:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo dpkg --install packages-microsoft-prod.deb`

---

Update the Repositories:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo apt update`

---

Install APT Transport for HTTPS:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo apt install --yes apt-transport-https`

---

Update the Repositories:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo apt update`

---

Install .Net:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo apt install --yes dotnet-sdk-5.0`

---

Add Arkane Systems to the Source List Directory:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://wsl-translinux.arkane-systems.net/apt/ /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wsl-translinux.list'`

---

Update the Repositories:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo apt update`

---

Install Genie:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`sudo apt install --yes systemd-genie`

---

Create the Sudoers File:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/genie" | sudo EDITOR="tee" visudo --file /etc/sudoers.d/$USER`

---

Create the Desktop Script:
Copy the code from below these instructions
Paste the code into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

```
# CREATE BASH SCRIPT

# Store block of text with here document
create_bash_script=$(cat << end_of_string

# Define necessary environment variables
export DISPLAY="\$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{ print \$2 }'):1.0"
export DESKTOP_SESSION="ubuntu"
export GDMSESSION="ubuntu"
export XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP="ubuntu"
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="ubuntu:GNOME"
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE="x11"
export XDG_BACKEND="x11"
export XDG_SESSION_CLASS="user"
export XDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop"
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS="/etc/xdg"
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="\$HOME/xdg"
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="\$HOME/.config"
export XDG_DATA_HOME="\$HOME/.local/share" 
export XDG_CACHE_HOME="\$HOME/.cache"
export XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="\$HOME/Desktop"
export XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="\$HOME/Documents"
export XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="\$HOME/Downloads"
export XDG_MUSIC_DIR="\$HOME/Music"
export XDG_PICTURES_DIR="\$HOME/Pictures"
export XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="\$HOME/Public"
export XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="\$HOME/Templates"
export XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="\$HOME/Videos"

# Start desktop environment
gnome-session

end_of_string
)

# Store username environment variable in lowercase
username=$(wslvar USERNAME | awk '{ print tolower($0) }') &&

# Save block of text in bash file
echo "${create_bash_script}" > "/mnt/c/users/$username/.ubuntu/02_start_desktop.sh"
```

---

Download the Shortcut Images:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`wget https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/9fbc8a44-circle-of-friends-web.zip`

---

Unzip the Shortcut Images:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`unzip -o 9fbc8a44-circle-of-friends-web.zip`

---

Create the Shortcut Icon:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`convert -resize 64x64 ./circle-of-friends-web/png/cof_orange_hex.png ubuntu.ico`

---

Exit WSL2:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`exit`

---

Create the VcXsrv Script:
Copy the code from below these instructions
Paste the code into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

```
# RELOAD VCXSRV SCRIPT

# Store username environment variable in lowercase
$username = $env:username.tolower()  

# Store block of text with here-string
$reload_vcxsrv_script = @"

# Stop vcxsrv proccess that contains "1.0" in the program window title
get-process vcxsrv | where { `$_.mainwindowtitle -like "*1.0*" } | stop-process

# Start vcxsrv process in a large program window on display number one
start-process "c:\program files\vcxsrv\vcxsrv.exe" -argument ":1 -ac -nowgl -multimonitors -dpms"

"@

# Save block of text in powershell file
echo "${reload_vcxsrv_script}" > $env:userprofile/.ubuntu/reload_vcxsrv.ps1
```

---

Create the Ubuntu Script:
Copy the code from below these instructions
Paste the code into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

```
# CREATE VISUAL BASIC SCRIPT

# Store username environment variable in lowercase
$username = $env:username.tolower()           

# Store block of text with here-string
$create_vbs_script = @"

' Run PowerShell script in background
set application = createobject("shell.application")
application.shellexecute "powershell", "-file c:\users\admin\.ubuntu\01_reload_vcxsrv.ps1", "", "", 0

' Allow PowerShell script to complete
wscript.sleep 3000

' Run Bash script in background
set shell= createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.run "wsl sudo genie -c bash /mnt/c/users/admin/.ubuntu/02_start_desktop.sh", 0

"@

# Save block of text in bash file
echo "${create_vbs_script}" > $env:userprofile/.ubuntu/03_start_ubuntu.vbs
```

---

Create the Shortcut Script:
Copy the code from below these instructions
Paste the code into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

```
# Store block of text with here-string
$create_shortcut_script = @"

# Define location variables
`$shortcut_location = "`$env:userprofile\.ubuntu\Ubuntu.lnk"
`$program_location = "`$env:userprofile\.ubuntu\03_start_ubuntu.vbs"

# Create shortcut
`$object = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
`$shortcut = `$object.createshortcut(`$shortcut_location)
`$shortcut.targetpath = `$program_location
`$shortcut.iconlocation = "`$env:userprofile\.ubuntu\ubuntu.ico"
`$shortcut.save()

"@

# Save block of text in powershell file
echo $create_shortcut_script > $env:userprofile/.ubuntu/04_create_shortcut.ps1
```

---

Open the Ubuntu Directory:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`cd c:\users\admin\.ubuntu`

---

Create the Shortcut:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`powershell.exe -file .\04_create_shortcut.ps1`

---

Open the Directory in Explorer:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into PowerShell
Press "Enter"

`explorer .`

---

Launch the Ubuntu Desktop:
Double-click the "Ubuntu" shortcut

---

Open Terminal:
Click "Activities" in the top-left corner
Enter "Terminal" into the search bar
Click "Terminal"

---

Disable the Screen Lock:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into Terminal
Press "Enter"

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false`

---

Install the Snap Store:
Copy the command from below these instructions
Paste the command into Terminal
Press "Enter"

`sudo snap install snap-store`

---