# How do I start using Python after installing a package in Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, python, anaconda

I have only installed Ubuntu to download [this](http://haselofflab.github.io/CellModeller/) package and it's my first time working with it. I installed Anaconda and Python 3 on Ubuntu, and then followed the installation steps on the website. I don't know how to run Python on it; I typed `cmgui` and I get this:

[image: (this is just a sample)]

I am confused about the Python 2 and about the "not a valid identifier" errors. What should I do?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question ([edit]) and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Please describe how you installed Ubuntu. Looks like you are using WSL. Also looks like `cmgui` requires a Desktop Environment (which is not included with WSL). Ubuntu applications in WSL cannot use the Windows desktop.

Comment: @user535733 exactly, I used WSL. Is there any other solution or do I need to reinstall Ubuntu in some other way? (cygwin, VirtualBox, dua boot...)?

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162808/run-ubuntu-desktop-on-wsl-ubuntu-18-04-lts for Ubuntu Desktop on WSL. Alternately, VirtualBox is easy and free and Ubuntu Desktop installs easily within it.