# Ubuntu desktop does not install

Tags: software-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu under WSL. I am now trying to install Ubuntu desktop. I have tried several times. I get many errors such as: Failed to preset unit. Transport endpoint is not connected.
Now stuck on 75% for hours. Not a great first experience.

As an amateur I'm not sure what I can add. Installed is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I then typed in "sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop". It immediately started doing this but occasionally get stuck as follows:

> "Failed to reload daemon: Transport endpoint is not connected."

It is now showing 80% so it is still installing but with errors it seems. It is now 5 hours.

```
Setting up ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon (1.10~22.04.1) ...
Failed to reload daemon: Transport endpoint is not connected
Failed to get unit file state for ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon.service: Transport endpoint is not connected
Failed to retrieve unit state: Transport endpoint is not connected
ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Setting up libsm6: amd64 (2:1.2.3-1build2) ...
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have a think about what we’ll need to know to help you - we can’t guess what hardware or version of Ubuntu you’re trying to install, not hope you’re trying to install. Might be worth re-creating your installation media (a at least checking it) - most people are able to install Ubuntu desktop edition without too much trouble on most standard hardware setups.

Comment: Are you sure WSL supports installing the desktop components on top of Windows? How would that even work?

Comment: What procedure are you following to install "Ubuntu under wsl"?  Please provide the URL.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Since Ubuntu Desktop relies on Systemd, which is probably the most "troublesome" part of WSL, things are always changing in this regard.  There are a few questions here already about the topic, so **for now**, I'm closing this as a duplicate.  I'll see if I can dig up others.  Please do give those a look and see if they help.  If not (which is likely), please edit your question with details of what happened when trying those methods, and I can hopefully reopen.  Thanks!

Comment: @Will Are noted in the question and the tag, this is Windows Subsystem for Linux, which has a *very* different installation method than it sounds like you are used to.  For instance, there's no media involved here - Canonical places Ubuntu in the Microsoft Store on Windows. However, your question about the version is useful, and I'm happy to see that the OP has edited that in.

Comment: Tony - [Here's another related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1388418/1165986) that I can't add to the header since it had no upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu running on WSL is not meant to run a full-featured Ubuntu desktop. From the WSL doc, [Run Linux GUI apps on the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps):

> Support for GUI apps on WSL does not provide a full desktop experience. It relies on Windows desktop, so installing desktop-focused tools or apps may not be supported. To request additional support, you can file an issue in the WSLg repo on GitHub.

WSL primarily provides a terminal-based Ubuntu / Linux system for development purposes. However, it is possible to launch single graphical apps from WSL, which integrate into the Windows desktop.

Some additional resources to read are:

- [Windows Subsystem for Linux Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/)
- [WSL docs from Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/wsl)

If you are looking for a full-featured desktop installation, you may better install Ubuntu Desktop in a virtual machine, e.g. using Microsoft's Hyper-V.