# How install Ubuntu Graphic on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been trying to install Ubuntu in a graphical environment for a long time, but unfortunately I cannot connect it to the WSL platform?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1507965/ubuntu-desktop-does-not-install/1507992#1507992

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  If you are referring to Ubuntu Desktop, then as mentioned in the other post, there are several questions and answers here already regarding that.  For the moment, I'm going to close your post as a duplicate of those as well.  If you have a different problem, then [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1508537/edit) your post to include more information, such as what you've tried along with any error messages you've received.  Reply to this comment with @NotTheDr01ds in your message for me to be notified of the changes so that I can consider reopening. Thanks!