# Why is my WSL Ubuntu 22.04 saying "Failed to configure: Unsupported session typer" when I ran gnome-shell?

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Why is my gnome-shell saying "Failed to configure: Unsupported session typer" in WSL Ubuntu 22.04?
When I ran

> gnome-shell

in my WSL Ubuntu 22.04 terminal, it said "Failed to configure: Unsupported session typer".
Is there anyways to fix this issue? I have been having this issue for a long time. I have tried upgrading and updating both WSL and Ubuntu 22.04 but still it doesn't work. I have installed gnome-shell too.
If someone knows the solution it would be a life saver.

EDIT:

It is not really similar to the following question.
[Run ubuntu-desktop on WSL (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162808/run-ubuntu-desktop-on-wsl-ubuntu-18-04-lts)
Also, I'm a beginner programmer so I'm sorry if I had done mistakes.

EDIT 2:
It has been solved.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run ubuntu-desktop on WSL (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162808/run-ubuntu-desktop-on-wsl-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

Comment: Thanks for the link but It doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Basically, the point is that you don't need to run the command `gnome-shell` in WSL. Running GNOME shell in WSL will just graphically overlap with your Windows taskbar, and it might confuse you. The correct way to run graphical applications on WSL is to set up WSLg, and then directly run the app you want (firefox, nautilus, etc.), without starting `gnome-shell`.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot.

Comment: I thought it was some kind of a shell or something.

Comment: There are two definitions of "shell" here. 1. A https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)#Command-line_shells is like bash, dash, csh, zsh, and runs inside your terminal. 2. A https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)#Graphical_shells is either the Windows taskbar, or `gnome-shell`. You already have one of each type of shell running, and you don't need to start another one.

Comment: Oh I get, thanks.

Comment: Please add an answer, and mark is as solution.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to, and shouldn't run `gnome-shell` in WSL. Copied from my comments on @davidbaumann's request.

On WSL, you need a X Or Wayland server running on the Windows 11 host's side to show graphical applications. Older answers here might suggest third-party X servers. In modern times, Microsoft has released a more integrated solution, WSLg. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps , it is enabled by default on new installs with `wsl --install`. To enable it for existing installations, there are further details at https://github.com/microsoft/wslg .

## Is `gnome-shell` some kind of a shell or something?

There are two definitions of "shell" here. 1. A https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)#Command-line_shells is like bash, dash, csh, zsh, and runs inside your terminal. 2. A https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)#Graphical_shells is either the Windows taskbar, or gnome-shell. You already have one of each type of shell running, and you don't need to start another one.

If you open two terminal windows, you have two command-line shells. If you run another bash inside one of the bashes (perfectly safe), you would have 3 command-line shells.

However, you do not want to run two graphical shells. A graphical shell is usually the taskbar plus some other things. You do not want two taskbars on screen! One might overlap the other, and confuse you when you try and click but the wrong taskbar gets clicked. Furthermore, `gnome-shell` says it manages window switching, which Windows 11 itself wants to manage. When you log into Windows, you have the perfectly functional graphical shell (one of the functions of `explorer.exe`) that comes with Windows. The only reason a bare-metal Ubuntu installation needs to start `gnome-shell` is because nothing else is providing a taskbar.

So basically, you want to skip trying to start `gnome-shell` and jump to trying to run the application you are trying to use. After WSLg is set up, just running `firefox` or `nautilus` in terminal should open the corresponding application window.