# Applications run through Bash on WSL aren't sharp

Tags: windows, xorg, gui, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've recently started using WSL and Ubuntu for some school projects. Today I installed an X server to run graphical applications such as Atom trough the Bash command line. The problem is that when I start these applications they aren't as "sharp" as when I run them through Windows. When beginning to use the laptop I had the same issue with windows as well but after "allowing Windows to fix blurry apps" in the settings the issue went away.

My question is if there's any way to have the applications run through Ubuntu look the same way or if I just have to live with it. Maybe I need to change the display settings and not do something with the subsystem but it's worth asking.

Here's a screenshot of the problem. The window to the left is run through Windows and the right one is run through Ubuntu:

[image: screenshot of the problem, the window to the left is run through Windows and the right one is run through Ubuntu]

Comment: If you are running WSL you can't be using Ubuntu 14.04 because the first version was 16.04 and the current is 18.04. As far as generic tips go you can check out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018/993331#993331 but it doesn't specifically address font resolution issues.

Comment: What X Server are you using? It usually has the option to do not scale the app

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez I'm using VcXsrv (XLaunch). When starting it i get to select display setting but I can't find anything that seems to relate to the issue.

Comment: Check this: https://superuser.com/a/1370548/281079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @CarlosRafaelRamirez the solution to the problem is explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1370361/blurry-fonts-on-using-windows-default-scaling-with-wsl-gui-applications-hidpi/1370548#1370548) (assuming you are using VcXsrv)

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer by clicking grey check mark next to it. This lets other people know the solution that works.