# Command not found error after trying to install mgltools on WSL

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, paths, alias

I am working on Ubuntu windows application. I want to use a tool and I have downloaded the file and install it is in /usr/local/bin. I want to access the tool from anywhere and for that I have write an alias in bashrc file. Now, while I call the tool it generating error. Kindly help me with this.

How I installed mgltools:

```
  398  tar xvzf mgltools_i86Linux2_1.5.6.tar.gz
  399  cd mgltools_i86Linux2_1.5.6/
  400  ./install.sh

*****@DESKTOP-*****:/usr/local/bin/mgl-tools/mgltools_i86Linux2_1.5.6$ ls
Data.tar.gz  MGLToolsPckgs.tar.gz        README  bin      install.sh  tcl8.4
LICENSES     Python2.5_i86Linux2.tar.gz  Tools   include  lib         tk8.4
```

After that, I have write following alias in bashrc file via vim and save it:

```
alias adt='sudo /usr/local/bin/mgl-tools/mgltools_i86Linux2_1.5.6/adt'

#source ~/.bashrc
```

When I call the tool this error is generated.

```
sudo: /usr/local/bin/mgl-tools/mgltools_i86Linux2_1.5.6/adt: command not found
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't see 'adt' in the output of `ls`, so the alias points to a nonexistent file.

Comment: Pictures of text are very hard to read; esp. a black terminal window within white background of askubuntu.  Please copy/paste the text as you have in other parts of your question.

Comment: I have changed the pictures, I hope it  will be better now.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it in Ubuntu 18.04 VirtualBox:

```
wget http://mgltools.scripps.edu/downloads/downloads/tars/releases/REL1.5.6/mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.6.tar.gz
tar xvzf mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.6.tar.gz
cd mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.6/
sudo ./install.sh -d /opt/mgl/
sudo cp initMGLtools.sh /opt/mgl/
```

Then add to `/etc/bash.bashrc`

```
export PATH=/opt/mgl/bin:$PATH
source /opt/mgl/initMGLtools.sh
```

But can you may test it directly:

`/opt/mgl/bin/adt` or `adt`

**Reference**:

[mgltools.scripps.edu - Instructions for Installing MGLTools on Linux](http://mgltools.scripps.edu/downloads/previous-releases/mgltools-1-5.4/instructions/linux/?searchterm=install)

[image: mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.6 - adt]

Comment: still not working   adt
sudo: /usr/local/bin/mgl-tools/mgltools_i86Linux2_1.5.6/bin/adt: command not found

Comment: sudo: /usr/local/bin/mgl-tools/mgltools_i86Linux2_1.5.6/bin/: command not found. I have add the installation method in description section kindly consider it.

Comment: ls /usr/local/bin/mgl-tools/mgltools_i86Linux2_1.5.6/bin/                                                        
f2py  ipython  pilconvert.py  pilfile.py  pilprint.py  pydoc   python-config  python2.5-config  smtpd.py  xmlproc_parse
idle  irunner  pildriver.py   pilfont.py  pycolor      python  python2.5      runPmv            wsdl2py   xmlproc_val

Comment: I see, there is no adt file. So, what should I do know I follow the installation instructions carefully. I don't understand what's the exact issue. I am working with this tool from last 3 years but I was using SUSE linux at that time and now Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rhea, updated my answer, it worked fine for me in 18.04.

Comment: It was a great help. I followed the above instructions still adt was not working then I come to know as I am using  ubuntu subsystem so I have to download Xming. After downloading it I set the Display=:0 in /etc/environment file and finally adt  command start working but after processing it generate this error "ImportError: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"  I don't find any solution for that, there was a solution on github but it's regarding matplot  library.

Comment: @Rhea could you edit and add an update to the question ? with full steps and error message.

Comment: I am not familiar with Windows subsystem . AFAIK you have two, other separate issues: X graphics server and 3D OpenGL libraries. I can't help much, but could you try solutions here, https://askubuntu.com/q/993225/26246 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/22360771/724406