# Can I run android studio on windows 10 Subsystem Linux

Tags: android, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In terms of compatibility and IO on files shared between Windows and Linux Subsystem: If I install Ubuntu image for WSL from the Microsoft Store, could this cause any file system problems when I try to run Android Studio from the WSL image?

This is due to the technical issues raised up here [Microsoft/WSL](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues), since 2017 up to now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018) Recommended requiremnets for Android Studio is 8GB RAM. If you can't run Android Studio in Windows then you can't run it in Linux either.

Comment: @karel  ,I have tried to go through that link,however this implies that wsl does not provide a fully fledged development environment features/services.

Comment: That's partially correct, however Windows 10 will introduce support for more of these features in WSL 2 which is scheduled to be released in April, 2020.

Answer (score 6):

For running Android Studio in WSL image you need to **enable WSL2** which is currently subject of Windows Insider Preview builds.

*Please note, that GUI applications are not officially supported by Microsoft, however it works and does not cause any filesystem problems in my case.*

You can find a whole guide to start GUI applications including enabling WSL2 here: https://autoize.com/xfce4-desktop-environment-and-x-server-for-ubuntu-on-wsl-2/
All you need is to **install VcSrv** or any alternative on Windows side (I recommend paid X410 as an alternative with better UX) and **xfce4 on Unix side and then configure Unix display to show in Windows** by `export DISPLAY=[unix ip]:0`

After you configure it, you can download and install Android Studio from https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads

You can face an error during installation: "Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool." - [see a related question on Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241640/error-unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool).
However, if you manually install missing libraries, it will complete the installation. I tried it and it works.

Install missing libraries with a recommended answer: `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6`

For information about connecting to USB device see this issue github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/issues/23 refering to this guide: github.com/rpasek/usbip-wsl2-instructions

A limitation is that WSL2 does not support nested virtualization at this time, so you will not be able to emulate an virtual Android device.

Comment: Can Android Studio running in WSL2 connect with a smartphone which is connected to the Windows 10 computer via a USB cable?

Comment: @karel Yes, see this issue https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/issues/23 refering to this guide: https://github.com/rpasek/usbip-wsl2-instructions