# can't open gedit on ubuntu warning unable to connect to server

Tags: gedit, editor

[error message when using gedit on ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cy1p.jpg)

I keep getting an error whenever I try to open gedit on ubuntu from Windows 10. I already redownloaded and updated gedit but still keep getting the same error.

Comment: *"from Windows 10"* meaning what, exactly? Are you using [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), or connecting to a remote Ubuntu server over SSH for example?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 subsystem for Linux. I'm using ubuntu locally on my desktop

Comment: Have you configured it to run graphical applications, as described in [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018) for example?

Comment: I just did it and I'm still getting the same error message

Comment: In the link that @steeldriver listed, did you run the command `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` from the second answer?  WSL still needs to know where the display is.  There is a chance that if you type in `echo $DISPLAY` it will probably come up blank until you type in that `export` command.

Comment: I fixed it by downloading VcXsrv from this website https://github.com/ArcticaProject/vcxsrv/releases