# trying run spyder on ubuntu Os on WSL

Tags: python

trying run spyder on ubuntu OS but getting this error:

(venv) ankur@W0226983:~$ spyder
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-ankur'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.

QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-ankur'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018)

Comment: In the linked question / answer above, please look at all answers as multiple steps may need to be performed.