# Can I use gedit in Ubuntu prompt on Windows?

Tags: command-line, gedit

I'm trying to use gedit editor in Ubuntu terminal on Windows. I don't have a full Linux OS, just installed Ubuntu prompt for Windows from MS store. I need this for my programming course. Is this possible at all? I installed gedit on my PC as well. But when I try to use it in the prompt, comes message "Command 'gedit' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install gedit
     I tried to install it in the suggested by this message way, but it gives me some errors. So I wonder if it's possible. Thank you in advance for help!
     When I try 'sudo apt install gedit', I'm getting the errors:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 amd64 2.26.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 amd64 2.26.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/webkit2gtk/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18_2.26.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/webkit2gtk/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.26.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: You will need to resolve the installation errors, then install an appropriate X server in Windows. See for example [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have no idea how to resolve these errors, neither what they even mean. I checked your link, but there's nothing there I can easily do. Should I consider that there's no easy way to use gedit in my case under Windows?

Comment: If you want further help, please [edit] your question to include the errors that resulted when you tried `sudo apt install gedit`

Comment: Thank you, I did that.

Comment: Thanks - did you remember to run `sudo apt update` first? the package versions that it's looking for don't appear to be the current ones

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I updated it, upgraded it and installed gedit. Now I have the following problem when I try to create a gedit file:                                                                                                                                                                     ~$ gedit test
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(gedit:4417): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:46:11.204: cannot open display:

Comment: So did you install + start an X server (Xming, VcXsrv or similar) on the Windows system?

Comment: OK, now I installed Xming and I started it. I can now use gedit in the Ubuntu prompt, even though every time I need to input 'ubuntu' in the Xming launcher - a trick which I tried, but am not even sure how it's working. So I can create now gedit files, but I'm still getting lots of error messages, I'll put them here in separate comment. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: (gedit:33): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 15:29:39.534: g_dbus_proxy_new_sync: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed                                                                                                                     (gedit:33): dconf-WARNING **: 15:29:41.807: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch= --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1

Comment: ** (gedit:33): WARNING **: 15:30:20.269: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported                                                                                   (gedit:33): dconf-WARNING **: 15:30:25.705: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch= --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1