# I have the Ubuntu WSL2, is it possible to run games like nSnake? how would i install it?

Tags: apt, software-installation, games, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Title says all. I have ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I downloaded it from the Microsoft store, and i was to install games on it. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install nSnake in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe # If you already have a root prompt (#) you don't need to preface any commands with sudo.
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install nsnake
```

To start nSnake run `nsnake` from the terminal, and it will open in the terminal because it's a terminal game.

In order to run graphical applications on WSL 2 see [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/q/993225/).

Comment: Its not working, it says there is an error. Here is a link the photo of my error message https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUHZy.png

Comment: @AtomicBadger I replied to your comment by editing my answer.

Comment: thank you! are there any other games i should get?

Comment: `sudo apt install frozen-bubble gnome-breakout gweled`  In order to run graphical applications on WSL 2 see [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/q/993225/). If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.

Comment: My favorite Linux game is sdl-ball (`sudo apt install sdl-ball`) and I got one of the top scores on it if the sdl-ball leaderboard is to be believed. If you're as competitive as I think you are you might want to try it after trying some of the easier games first. sdl-ball is hard to play, and it's a real waste of time if you've got anything more important to do. You can't find this shadowy game in the Software app anymore, but it's still in the default Ubuntu repositories.