# How to fix Error: Can't open display: (null) on "Ubuntu for Windows 10" Terminal

Tags: 20.04, windows, windows-10

I am using this [windows terminal](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/ubuntu-on-windows#1-overview), and when trying to execute

```
echo hello world | xclip -sel clip
```

for example, I receive Error:

> Can't open display: (null)

error.

I installed

```
sudo apt-get install xorg
```

Also tried
`export DISPLAY=:0` (and also 1)

but the xclip gives me the same error.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Explain your question  Are you in a terminal without any display manager like - recovery mode or Alt + ctrl + f5 mode then you need to install a display manager like gdm3 or lightdm.?

Comment: I simply use this windows terminal for Ubuntu. So, you say I need to install gdm3 or lightdm? Isn't the xorg enough?  I install gdm3 and tried the echo command again : still getting the same error

Comment: Nope its not also why are you using ubuntu terminal in windows it is not really good to use it in windows because it may malfunction.

Comment: "Ubuntu on Windows allows you to use Ubuntu Terminal and run Ubuntu **command line utilities** including bash, ssh, git, apt and many more." See [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018)