# Error: couldn't open display [IP ADDRESS] on WSL 2 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, display, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having issues displaying glxgears or any other GUI application, like Gazebo or rviz.

I have VcXsrv as my windows X server for WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04.
I followed this link for instructions: https://lifesaver.codes/answer/ros-gazebo-black-screen-3368, but this is the end result:

```
Error: couldn't open display
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

Comment: Oops - Missed that you said 20.04 in the question.  In that case, definitely check out the answers that were linked.  They should answer the question for you.  Let us know if they don't - Thanks!