# echo $DISPLAY doesn't print anything

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to run `echo $DISPLAY` but it doesn't return anything, just a blank line.

I read that it's supposed to return something like `:0`. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  You have this tagged [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux], but you don't say which Windows version.  I'm assuming Windows 10 if you don't have a `DISPLAY` variable, since Windows 10 WSL doesn't support Linux graphical apps by default.  See this question for ways to do that on Windows 10 or Windows 11 - [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux).  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I see, thank you! I've edited my question with the Windows version. I've tried to run `export DISPLAY=:0` and at least now I get `:0` when running `echo $DISPLAY`. 
Plus I get a different error in the code I'm trying to run, so I guess that's progress!

Comment: Setting the variable to `:0` will only work under WSL1.  As noted in my answer on the question I linked, on WSL2 (with Windows 10, as I assume you are using), you'll need `export DISPLAY="$(hostname).local:0"`.  You'll also need a third-party X11 server such as VcXsrv.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. How do I find out the hostname? And how shall I get the third-party X11 server?

Comment: The command that I provided above should actually set the DISPLAY variable with the correct hostname for you without anything additional.  If not, what happens if you `echo "$(hostname).local:0"`?  As for the X server, there are quite a few links to [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) in the question linked above.  I think some others are mentioned and linked as well in there.