# Why does Atom Editor (running on ubuntu WSL) crash everytime I type, even on a new file

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, atom

I am running Atom Editor on ubuntu on Windows 10 WSL. I am connecting to the Xserver via RDP as was suggested in the answer to this question: [Error running Atom Ubuntu on WSL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404675/error-running-atom-ubuntu-on-wsl/1404738?noredirect=1#comment2439909_1404738)

1. I RDP and log into Xorg.
2. I startup ubuntu and I start Atom (so far so good)
3. I create a new file on Atom and try to type. As soon as I type the first character it crashes.

Note: typing in the regular text editor in the GUI works fine

I dont know how to get the logs to see what the actual error is. The popup when it crashes says to report on Git...but I dont know how to get the error to report on git even. It could be a bug I guess, but more likely its me... or maybe a problem with the Atom installation. I didnt install it via RDP but in the Ubuntu terminal in Win 10.

Would appreciate guidance in how to find the cause and how to fix it.

Thank you

Comment: Hmmm - It's working for me under a xrdp session.  How are you launching Atom?  If you open a terminal in Xfce and then run `atom` from inside it, do you get any logs/output in that terminal window?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I am just running it from the Xfce GUI in the xrdp session. (Programs/Development/Atom), like we solved in the other question.  Are these logs located in var/log or somewhere else. I looked in the xrdp.log but there was nothing there about Atom. When I try ~/.xsession-errors, I get "permission denined".  When I go in the GUI to System/Logs and choose application logs, there are no results. Could you tell me where I get the logs for the Atom crash please.

Comment: One more bit which might be relevant. When I start Atom, I get a message that an application needs to access Keyring and to enter a pw, which I do correctly.