# Opening a pdf on Ubuntu on WSL

Tags: 20.04, files, pdf, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with WSL2 in Windows 10.
I need to open a file `Rplot.pdf` on Ubuntu.

I've tried:

First:

```
xdg-open Rplots.pdf
```

I got:

> Error: no "view" mailcap rules found for type "application/pdf"

Next:

```
gio open Rplots.pdf
```

I got:

> (gio open:343): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 10:06:22.333: g_dbus_connection_flush: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed                                                                                                               xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:                                                                                    xterm: DISPLAY is not set

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  For starters, WSL on Windows 10 does not support graphical Linux applications.  The supported method is to upgrade to Windows 11, but there are [additional options](https://askubuntu.com/q/993225/1165986) for Windows 10, but you'll need to manually configure them.  You may also have a DBus issue, but solve the basics (displaying GUI app) first, and then we'll work on that if it still occurs.