# Cool Retro Term not displaying

Tags: command-line, application-development, windows-subsystem-for-linux, qt

I'm trying to start up cool retro term, and am running into an issue. When I run it using "cool-retro-term" in the terminal, the new window pops up, but it's see-through, as in you can see the content in the window behind it and cool retro term isn't displaying anything. I run it in Ubuntu and get the following message:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot Konsole::TerminalDisplay_QML_62::close()
loadAllColorSchemes
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
```

I originally installed it with `sudo apt install cool-retro-term` and there were no errors with that. I'm wondering if this might have something to do with Qt? Any insight and how I might remediate this would be supremely appreciated!

Comment: @guiverc Ah yes, apologies. It's on the Windows Subsystem for Linux, 20.04.

Comment: Please use EDIT and add the info to the question not as a comment.

Comment: Also, which Windows version are you using?  If Windows 10, what X server are you running?  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Sorry for the delay, but I'm indeed using Windows 10, running WSL via the Windows Terminal, which I believe utilizes...Cygwin? But don't quote me on that.

Comment: @ZapRowsdower No worries.  If it's WSL on Windows 10, then there's no support for GUI applications like `cool-retro-term` built-in.  (Side-note:  No, Cygwin's a totally different thing.)  You'll need to use one of the solutions in [How to run GUI apps with Windows Subsystem for Linux (Super User)](https://superuser.com/a/1669770/1210833) or (the much more detailed) [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/q/993225/1165986) (here on AU).

Comment: I'm going to mark this as a duplicate of [that AU one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux) (we get a lot of questions like this), but if you still run into an issue after trying that, let me know via comment and we'll see if we can find you a different solution.  Thanks!